# Installing NVIDIA Drivers to 14.04?

Tags: drivers, 14.04, nvidia

I am running a Samsung Chronos 7 with an NVIDIA Geforce GT 640m graphics card. I would like to utilize this graphics card so that I may use my computer for various computer games. Previously, when I tried to install drivers via the sudo command for downloading the current drivers for my card, Ubuntu would not boot past the splash screen, and eventually "gave up on finding the root". I am starting from a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04, and I request some help on what to do.

Comment: what was the exact package you installed using sudo? ( i.e. nvidia-310, nvidia-319, or nvidia-updates etc. )

Comment: you might find this helpfull as well http://www.webupd8.org/2014/01/prime-indicator-lets-you-quickly-switch.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First method

1. go to the software center
2. click "Edit"
3. select "Software Sources" from the dropdown menu
4. click on the "Alternative Drivers" tab and select the proprietary
   Nvidia driver from the list of drivers for your system.
5. when you are done, reboot for your changes to take effect

Alternatively, you could install the proprietary driver from Nvidia from here http://www.geforce.com/drivers/results/76884

**1-** Download the file to your Downloads folder and then execute the
    following commands in a terminal:

```
cp ~/Downloads/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-340.24.run ~/nvidia.run
chmod +x ~/nvidia.run
```

**2-** Press CTRL + ALT + F2 and sign in the text console with your username and password. After you sign in, type the following command to terminate the X-session:

```
sudo service lightdm stop
```

If you are using gnome-shell you may have to use gdm instead of lightdm.

**3-** Use the following commands to install the driver:

```
cd ~/ && sudo ./nvidia.run
```

Follow the instructions; it's safe to accept the default file location to write the config file if the installer asks.  Reboot when you are done for the changes to take effect.